# Create parameters GA and powerbi

Tags: powerbi, m

**Objective:** I would like to create parameters to let the user enter their GA credentials to import data into powerbi.

**What I tried**

```
let
    Source = GoogleAnalytics.Accounts(),
    #""&Number.ToText(Account)&"" =Source{[Id=""&Number.ToText(Account)&""]}[Data],
    #"##-######-##" = #""&Number.ToText(Account)&""{[Id="##-#####-##"]}[Data],
    #"######" = #"##-######-##"{[Id="#######"]}[Data],
    #"Added Items" = Cube.Transform(#"######",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the double quotes here:

```
let
    [...]
    #""&Number.ToText(Account)&"" =
```

It should be:

```
let
    [...]
    #"&Number.ToText(Account)&" =
```